# How to disable spring-boot executable jar default log file?

Tags: logging, spring-boot

As seen in the [Spring Boot docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment-install.html#deployment-initd-service) an executable jar linked to /etc/init.d/foo will create a log file named /var/log/foo.log

Unfortunately I can't find an option to disable the usage of this file as I have logging configured via my logback.xml

Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the startup script is always using a log file, so unfortunately you probably won't be able to remove it: [launch.script](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-tools/spring-boot-loader-tools/src/main/resources/org/springframework/boot/loader/tools/launch.script)

EDIT: Or, you could try a hack by setting `LOG_FOLDER` to `/dev` and `LOG_FILENAME` to `null` as described [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment-install.html#deployment-script-customization-conf-file)

Comment: After checking the init script and thinking about this all day, this is the best way I came up with as well. It's very hacky so I didn't do it, but it should work I agree.

Comment: pointing to `/dev/null` may cause some issues, see run script where `chown "$run_user" "$log_file"`

Answer (score 0):

You can change the file name and folder either with environment variables or in a {jarname}.conf file, as described here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment-install.html#deployment-script-customization

You can't turn it off completely though, and i suppose you also don't want to do that, since you might want to have errors logged, which occur at startup before Logback is initialized.